# how to pass values in one xaml page to another xaml page in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Give Me Detail Explanation and Code For QueryString in silverlight.i.e i want to pass one xaml page values into another xaml page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Silverlight Navigation Framework" and you will find a number of articles which "Give You Detail Explanation" and a few cover "Code For QueryString".  Here is a simple [Blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/07/silverlight-3-s-new-navigation-framework.aspx) that covers all the bases very succinctly.

Comment: Thank U Sir ,
Can U Give idea For Navigation In Windows Phone 7.
In First Xaml Page I Want To Place imags if whenever click on particular image then zoomin  that image can be displayed in nextpage .